# I can't press the close button at the end

Tags: javascript, html, css

got a question about js. Wanted to add a 'finish' button to my textadventure. The js function I have included externally. Now the problem is that i have different html documents, if i open and close a html document by pressing the button it works. But if I go through from the start document to the last html document, the button doesn't work. 
Do you have any idea?

Here is my close

```js
function windowClose() {
  window.open('', '_parent', '');
  window.close();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: What does "close" mean? If you want to do window.close(), it will only work in a window you opened with script yourself from the same site you will close the window from

Comment: @mplungjan for example: i have 1234.html i have window.close, when i press the button shutdown then it shuts down. I also have a start.html when i go to the exact the button it doesnt work. My question is if i can realize the 2nd way.

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing code and how you call start from 1234 or other way around

Comment: i uploaded my code to github every file can you check it out start is the start file. i have some buttons in it the 'beenden' button should close the file.

Comment: https://github.com/MrMops19/Program

Answer (score 0):

Your close is not supposed to work on any browser anymore. It is a hack. If you managed to close my browser (and therefore kill my history) I would be quite annoyed.
Your pages are so short, you can have all of them in one page and just show/hide each path. You can even ajax them into a popped div and just hide the div when ending

For example [like this](http://plungjan.name/ee/advent/start.html)

The example only loads start and WegAA1.html, look at the new source of the sub pages - for example WegAA1.html

Note I moved the buttons into the text div and added

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

to start.html

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".btn", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop possible submission
    const $div = $("#text");
    let pageURL = $(this).data("href"); // the string in the data-href attribute of the button
    $div.fadeOut("slow", function() {
      $div.load(pageURL+" #text", function() {  
        $div.fadeIn("slow")
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
...
  <!--Teile des Dokuments definieren -->
  <div id="text"> Claudette geht mit ihrem Hund Nachts spazieren. Es ist Wochenende und sie hat im Moment nichts besseres zu tun, da sie viel Druck von der Schule hat und sie dadurch derzeit keinen Kopf für andere Sachen hat. Darauf hin schreibt sie William an, er ist
    ein guter Freund auf den sie sich immer verlassen kann. Dieser ist zwar kein gutes Vorbild da er raucht, aber das hält ihn nicht davon ab ein guter Mensch zu sein. Glücklicherweise schreibt dieser innerhalb von 5 Minuten auch schon zurück. Er wohnt
    nicht weit von Claudette weg und schlägt vor sie beim Spazieren gehen zu begleiten....
    <div id="option-buttons" class="btn-grid">
      <button class="btn" data-href="WegAA1.html">Versuchen diesen zu Reparieren </button>
      <button class="btn" data-href="WegBB1.html">Erst einmal weiter suchen </button>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: uff thanks for help but i am a completly noob. i have to do it for my classproject. i know its quiet bad but i dont know anything about it all it is too difficult to understand

Comment: The code is complete. Just move all buttons into the text div

Comment: <img src="..." alt="..." border="0"></a> what is this? should be this empty?

Comment: I hid your image when I copied from your git. It is not relevant to the question

Comment: The +" #text" is to only copy the text div

Comment: And what is with the rest of it. I have when i click on the button more textes i dont know how to realize that. I dont know how your method can work. thinking errors :D

Comment: My script assumes you move the buttons inside the text div in each page. Then it will load that div into the text div on the start page. Every time you click on a button, it will read the data-href from the button, so change the onclick to the data-href I show above. I can make you a working example to test I do not have typos in my script

Comment: Yea a example would be great.

Comment: See update. You can click on the first button to load the WegAA1 - I did not copy the rest